# New Relic create alert based on custom events

Tags: newrelic

We report custom events to New Relic using their API https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/insights/event-data-sources/custom-events/apm-report-custom-events.

Is there a way to create an alert if there is more than X amount of these custom events in a certain time frame.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `event_name` WHERE `field` = 'OFAC' SINCE 30 minutes ago
```

I am getting an error saying: `Invalid clauses in alert conditions: SINCE`

Note `event_name` and `field` are replaced with the string.

Answer (score 0):

use a nrql alert?

Get your nrql query then remove the Since 30 minutes

SELECT function(attribute)
FROM Event
WHERE attribute [comparison] [AND|OR ...]

e.g

```
nrql_query = "FROM K8sVolumeSample SELECT latest(fsUsedPercent) FACET podName, 
volumeName, pvcName WHERE clusterName IN ('cluster-prod') "
```

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts-applied-intelligence/new-relic-alerts/alert-conditions/create-nrql-alert-conditions

We use them via terraform.
The docs give a good example https://registry.terraform.io/providers/newrelic/newrelic/latest/docs/resources/nrql_alert_condition

The same query you use for a dashboard you can use for an alert. For dashboard SELECT count(*) FROM `event_name` WHERE `field` = 'OFAC' TIMESERIES SINCE 30 minutes ago or something similar

e.g For a count example - to get the count for unique k8 objects

```
SELECT uniqueCount(K8sNodeSample.entityId) AS 'Nodes', 
uniqueCount(K8sNamespaceSample.clusterName) AS 'Clusters', 
uniqueCount(K8sNamespaceSample.entityId) AS 'Namespaces', 
uniqueCount(K8sDeploymentSample.entityId) AS 'Deployments', 
uniqueCount(K8sPodSample.entityId) AS 'Pods', 
uniqueCount(K8sContainerSample.containerID) AS 'Containers' FROM 
K8sNodeSample, K8sNamespaceSample, K8sDeploymentSample, K8sPodSample, 
K8sContainerSample  WHERE clusterName IN ('cluster-prod')
```